# Battery cuts on a moped when off the kick stand

Tags: starting, moped

I have done a valve adjustment on my 50 cc Pantere Fusion moped, and in the process my ground wire to my moped came completely off. I don't know if that's my problem or not though. I adjusted the valves on my moped to .003. That's what my local moped shop (Lesslie Motorsports) told me to set it at.

I tried to ground the one negative ground wire to the frame and hooked it to the battery. It cranks just fine if it's on the kick stand and I'm sitting on it. But as soon as I take it off the kick stand it cuts off. The thing is it won't even turn over if it's not up in the kick stand and I have to be sitting on it.

Answer (score 4):

I checked the service manual for your vehicle.  I'm not sure if it's the correct year.

Most motorcycles have a kickstand ignition cutout.  If you put it in gear with your kickstand down then it kills the ignition so you can't ride the motorcycle with the kickstand down.

The service manual does not show this type of a switch on your vehicle.  I also checked the entire wiring diagram for the ignition system and can't find a device on your bike that would explain your condition.

So, here is the [service manual](https://absolutelyscooters.net/pdf/PANTERRA%2050cc%20Street%20Scooter%20Service%20Manual.pdf).  Section 15 is where the ignition system starts.

Starting on page 21 there are troubleshooting guides that may be of some assistance.  Weird issue, I wish I could contribute more.